# React HigherOrderComponents in combination with flowtype

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I got a little problem with understanding Reacts Higher Order Components in combination with flowtype and Props declaration.

I have 2 kinds of HOCs:

**Component inside modal:**

```
inModal() => React.Component<{modal: Modal}>
```

In this HOC is simply create a new Modal (some react-less logic, i already implemented) and pass the modal object as property to the given component (so i can access close handlers and so on inside my component).

**Authentication-Secured Component:**

```
needsAuthentication() => React.Component<{auth: Authentication}>
```

So i can provide some critical functionality like disable-account and so on and reuse the authentication process over several components.

Now both of them work. And i managed to put those 2 together by writing:

```
inModal(needsAuthentication(DisableAccount))
```

My problem is, that inModal needs a component capable of handling a property called "modal" and needsAuthentication needs the component to be capable of handling a property "auth". Until now that was fine, because i always used those 2 HOCs in Combination. But now i am building a compoment, that is not working inside of a modal but needs the authentication.

An here my issue with understanding HOCs and flowtype becomes a real problem.

I created a new component, that needs to have a property passed but i can not define my needsAuthentication HOC to return a Component taking that specific property as it would break everything else. I could make my new component capable of handling a modal property and hack my way through this jungle but i would rather try to actually fully understand the matter.

I had a look at [this](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/) but my frustration/confusion level is already very high, so i cant really understand all of it.

[This should demonstrate my problem](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nQCQBCBABccVDCjAAdgHMANHQC+9RizYAVZAGssqAIIBXGAAtOEMHD6ChyM+cn9UJLJOmzFqlaoYEJnL4wBBycABGaFgAwiSQclhyMAAUYFyoklbcAJSS2HgwACQAchAAJmz2lDAmUOEpwkIAPOXAAG4AfFGoHgLp1qgAdKIQqs0A9G1dwjlqAUEhYXCJWOXGTkkwwLjI22EpceBhW-lUMENHCVvaWs26BhsW2Z15mOeX8SfJt6zN-KpOgJhDU6g0crYgfYhKD6nBGkJEa0Op0mkirt94I4LDx+K53JIAETY8yE1SqOATVFCOC0uAtKYoppzIT+fx0XBhaRSLC4OprABC0QxiWSthWWDWT3MWx2e1CchSPViX1FMByGkCwX24RAyHkKQh1SwtThCJavT5lHKQt6Iq2cFGPEJUSghMp1LmqiAA)

I would be very happy if someone could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nQCQBCBABccVDCjAAdgHMANHQC+9RizYAVZAGssqAIIBXGAAtOEMHD6ChyM+cn9UJLJOmzFqlaoYEJnL4wBBycABGaFgAwiSQclhyMAAUYFyoklbcAJSS2HgwACQAchAAJmz2lDAmUOEpwkIAPOXAAG4AfFGoHgLp1qgAdKIQqs0A9G1dwjlqAUEhYXCJWOXGTkkwwLjI22EpceBhW-lUMENHCVvaWs26BhsW2XAAZChyTJ15mOeX8SdkrdWM1kJ9OgJhDU6g0crYIfYhND6nBGkJ0a0Op0mhiroD4I4LDx+K53JIAESE8zk1SqOATbFCODMuAtKZYppzIT+fx0XBhaRSLC4OprABC0TxiWSthWWDWT3MWx2e1CchSPViAOlMByGkCwX24RAyHkKTh1SwtRRaJavRFlHKEt6Uq2cFGPHJUSg5PpjLmqiAA), his can be done by using the magical "any" type. But that does feel like using the "sledgehammer". So i wont accept this for now.